# I am trying to find a formula where the outcome can add or subtract a value from a row number.

Tags: excel

I am trying to find a formula where the outcome can add or subtract a value from a row number. e.g.

The formula I am looking for should do (imaginary) =cel(D(5+1), so that it refers to cel C6 instead of C5, the +1 or -1 should be the outcome of a formula or in a separate cel, so that i can refer or in the formula itself.

Does anyone have a solution?

Rene

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by using `INDEX` function, this formula will give you the nth cell in column C

`=INDEX(C:C,n)`

so you can derive n from another formula or include a row number, e.g.

`=INDEX(C:C,ROW()+1)`